# How to say "streak"?

Tags: single-word-requests

When you make a lesson every day on Duolingo, you have a streak of x days.

Which word/expression one would preferably use for that in Esperanto? Which other meanings would it also have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been saying *sinsekvo*. I never gave it much thought.

Checking PIV, I'm confident that *sinsekvo* is OK. Of the other suggestions so far, *serio* also seems good after checking PIV.

Answer (score 10):

I would probably use ***serio da tagoj*** or just ***serio*** for short. Maybe even ***tagserio***? (Please correct me if this is wrong.)

Answer (score 6):

A streak is a stripe, so you could say *strio* or *tagstrio*. Five-day streak: *kvintaga strio*.

*Serio* is also correct of course, but *strio* seems more vivid.

Comment: None of the definitions in PIV seem to support this usage of *strio*.

Comment: Picture a calendar in your mind and you will "get" it.

Comment: I can picture it - but what I'm picturing is the etymology of the English term. As for actual definitions and usage, I don't think *strio* is supported. My own preference is for *sinsekvo* but examples of *serio* used for long series of years are very easy to turn up. *Sinsekvo* is supported by existing expressions such as *neinterrompita sinsekvo de malfeliĉoj*.

Comment: I don't really understand the comment about how a streak is a stripe.  When I hear or think about the word "streak", I don't associate it with a "stripe".  Maybe it's just that I've never heard a streak also called a stripe. I still don't understand it when I picture a calendar in my head either.